# Text on my website next Js with ContentFul

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have created a content model and added a lot of content. Inside the description tag I have developed all the content, including Bold tags, images, videos, etc.

[image]

In the preview everything looks perfect, with the format it has to have but when I show it on my blog it shows as plain text. What am I doing wrong?

My URL: https://blanco-y-en-batea.vercel.app/blog-post?post=Identidad-digital%2C-una-renuncia-imperdonable

Ty for all.

Comment: Please check your HTML does having CSS style or not?

Comment: I have Css but not is this i think. The object of contenful, for example, desccription, is a plane text... :S

Comment: It should have styles (CSS, or any format) along with the HTML to make them bold, underline. What is your text format (HTML or Markdown or something else?) Could you debug/view the HTML/post content before rendering on the website?

Comment: How could I do it? The truth is that I do not understand why this happens

Comment: You can `console.log` the post content, and show the code for rendering it. You can edit your question to embed these information